# Capturing all occurences with RegEx

Tags: regex

I have a string like this:

```
page-9000,page-template,page-type,page-category-128,image-196,image-197,image-194,image-195,listing-latest,rss-latest,even-more-info,even-more-tags
```

I made a regex to check all the occurrences within the string:

```
^(page\-9000|rss\-latest|listing\-latest\-no\-category|category\-128)(,.+)?$
```

I want it to match all the ocurrences.

In this case:

```
page-9000, rss-lates,- listing-latest, category-128.
```

Instead it only matches the first occurence (`page-9000`) and ignores the rest.

Any advice?

Comment: Occurencies of what?

Comment: Did you forget the `/g` modifier? What language are you using?

Comment: You may use: this regex: `\b(page-9000|rss-latest|listing-latest|category-128)\b`

Comment: `/page-9000|rss-latest|listing-latest-no-category|category-128/g` will extract all of them. As anubhava suggests, `/\b(?:page-9000|rss-latest|listing-latest-no-category|category-128)\b/g` will get them as whole words. What is the regex library/programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `^` and `$`. If you are searching for `\b(page-9000|rss-latest|listing-latest-no-category|category-128)\b` all occurence are matched. Unescaping `-` is also unnecessary, as it is only used inside character sets (`[]`).